# How to setup Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment for Django projects?

Tags: django, selenium, hudson, fabric

I am researching about how to set up CI and continuous deployment for a small team project for a Django based web application. Here are needs:

- Developer check in the code into a hosted SVN server (unfuddle.com)
- A CI server detects new checkin, check out the source, build, run functional tests.
- If tests all passed, deploy the code to the webserver on Amazon EC2.

For now, the CI server is also responsible to run the functional tests. I figured out that I can use Husdon as the CI server, use Selenium to run functional tests, and use Fabric to deploy the build to remote web server in Amazon cloud.

I am new to Django development and not very familiar with opensource tools. My questions are:

1. I can find some information to integrate hudson with selenium, but I couldn't find much information on how to integrate Fabric to Hudson as well. Is this setup viable? Do you see problems?
2. How do I integrate and deploy database changes? Most likely in the early stage we will change database schema very often with code changes. I used to use Visual Studio and the database project made it very simple to deploy. I wonder if there is "established, well-supported" way to do that.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you very much with continuous integration/deployment - at my work we used CruiseControl and it acted very much as you describe, but I didn't have anything to do with setting it up.

However in answer to your second question, on database changes, the current state of the art in Django is to use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), which has just released version 0.7. It works well in a CI environment, as db migrations are stored alongside the code for each app, so the CI server can be set to run them automatically before running the tests.